# Wait in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to coding still so the easier the code the better and if you could provide an explanation that would be greatly appreciated!

I have the code
 `circle1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"circle2.png"];`
Currently I am using `sleep(1.0)` but from what I can understand sleep pauses the UIView so nothing moves on the screen.

What I would like is for this to happen:

```
circle1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"circle2.png"]; // This changes the circles image
wait(2.0) // I know this isn't objective-c code but I'm unsure on how to create a pause without pausing the screen (if that makes any sense)
circle1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"circle1.png"]; // Circle 1 image changes back to original picture after 2 seconds
```

My question is there a way to create a pause but not have the screen to freeze (so with sleep).

I've read up that there's a way with NSTimers but I haven't got  this code in a selector so I'm not sure how that with work.

Any help would be massively helpful! I want to become an app developer after leaving school so every answer will help :)

Comment: What do you want to pause? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I was typing it fairly quickly as I needed to go out. I would like a pause between the circle1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"circle2.png"]; and my other lines of code but I don't want it to completely pause the application so nothing is moving on the screen if that makes sense.

Comment: That doesn't clarify much. Update your question with more relevant code. Show the whole method that contains the line you originally posted. And explain what waiting needs to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to execute successively, pausing in between.  The simplest to explain is using blocks deferred by GCD.

```
// change the image immediately
circle1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"circle2.png"];

// 2 seconds later, change the image again
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    circle1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"differentImage.png"];
});

// 4 seconds later (important: 4 seconds after the immediate change) do it again
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 4 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    circle1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"differentDifferentImage.png"];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense compared to other explanations and examples. I will insert that into my code and try it out. Thanks again!